# Unexpected number in Wordpress wp_get_attachment_thumb_url

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to print url of the thumbnail out side the wordpress directory, the url works but the problem is I am always getting a number before that url.

This is the code I am playing with,

```
<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/personal/wordpress/wp-load.php'); query_posts('showposts=1');  if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php echo wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( the_id() ) )?>

<?php endwhile; else: echo "no posts"; endif; ?>
```

This is the output:

```
5http://localhost/personal/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/facebookhero-150x150.jpg
```

I have already tried string replace, like this `str_replace(the_id(),"", wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( the_id() ))` but it does not work, in fact when I have tried:

```
 <?php echo "|".wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( the_id() ) )?>
```

Most interestingly this is what I get:

```
5|http://localhost/personal/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/facebookhero-150x150.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine:

```
simplexml_load_string(get_the_post_thumbnail())->attributes()->src
```